# Modifying / Setting a String returned from an Accessor Method

Tags: java, string

I'm using a specific API which has a method "getName()". getName() returns a string. Is it possible to modify that String? There is no modifier method included in the API, and the String getName() returns is private. I cannot modify the API.

Comment: Hi @Ashtheking, welcome to Stack Overflow. You don't need to put the language in the title of your question when it's already in the tags, so I've gone ahead and edited the question title for you. Hope that's okay :-)

Comment: See the answer from cularis with regard to your question, but also consider that if the API doesn't provide means to modify the value, perhaps they don't want you to be doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to prevailing opinion, it *is* possible to change the contents of a String object on JDK versions 1.5 and newer, but I (and probably everyone else here) would strongly discourage it for many reasons. Strings were never meant to be changed, and they're just not built for it, meaning any attempt to do so will quickly get quite messy. That said, if you need it as an absolute last resort or else the world is going to end kind of thing, here's a bare-bones way to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String foo = "foo";
    System.out.println("foo's hash value: " + foo.hashCode());
    Field stringValueField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    stringValueField.setAccessible(true);
    stringValueField.set(foo, "bar".toCharArray());
    Field stringHashField = String.class.getDeclaredField("hash");
    stringHashField.setAccessible(true);
    stringHashField.set(foo, 0);
    System.out.println("foo's new value: " + foo);
    System.out.println("foo's new hash value: " + foo.hashCode());
}
```

Make careful note, however, of the other fields in String: offset and count. You'll have to deal with those fields, too, depending on how you change the String's value. Finally, and maybe most importantly, you have to consider what would happen if you modify an [interned String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).

Comment: Thanks. I don't think i'll use it, if it's this end-of-the-world bad. I think it could also cause problems, considering that the method is for the username of a client connected to the server.

Answer (score 3):

No. Strings are immutable. If there is no setter in the API, you cannot change the contents of `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in the Java language, meaning it is impossible to modify any `String` object. (All the String methods that appear to modify the string, such as `concat` and `append`, really just create and return a new `String` and leave the old one untouched.)

If you need to modify the `String` locally, you can just use concatenations or replacements on your local reference. If you need to modify the `String` that `getName()` will return, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your code everywhere where you want to use X.getName() from the specific API you can use a proxy class Y that uses X.getName() to do all your changes in Y.getName(). That makes it easy if one day the specific API changes (you only have to change one place).

To change X.getName() behaviour within the specific API you can use some bytecode manipulation (ex. http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/ ) at runtime. 
But this should be the absolut last resource.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that getName() returns the value of a field called `name`  In which case you can change it using reflections.